# Custom list row in ListView graphical layout

Tags: android, xml, listview

There are many many posts and an infinite number of questions on how to create a custom row and add it to a ListView. All the posts I find however, use Java code to set the custom row layout file to the list. Most samples do something like this:

```
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>
    (this,R.layout.row_layout,R.id.text1,colors);
```

I was wondering if there isn't a way to do this in the XML files directly? Isn't there a property on the ListView where you can set a custom layout file for the rows?

The reason I'm asking is because I'm trying to do all (most) of my layout work in the Graphical Layout tool in Eclipse and I would like to be able to preview my layouts in it without launching the app.

Surely this should be possible in one way or another? If I could to it in the XML I would be very happy but if I have to write a custom class that will show up in the "custom" part of the graphical layout editor that will do as well.

Many thanks for your time.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It is possible to preview ListViews in the graphical editor. Just right-click the ListView and  choose "Preview List Content". Then select "Custom" and choose the custom row layout.

Here's an example:

my_custom_list.xml

```
 <ListView android:id="@android:id/list"
           android:layout_width="match_parent"
           android:layout_height="match_parent"
           android:layout_weight="1"
           android:drawSelectorOnTop="false">
     <!-- Preview: listitem=@layout/account_list_item -->
 </ListView>
```

my_custom_row.xml

```
<CheckBox
    android:id="@+id/icon"

    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"

    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_marginRight="6dip"
     />

<TextView  
    android:id="@+id/secondLine"

    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="26dip" 

    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/icon"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"

    android:singleLine="true"
    android:ellipsize="marquee"
    android:text="mail@mail.com" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"

    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/icon"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_above="@id/secondLine"
    android:layout_alignWithParentIfMissing="true"

    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:text="Account name" />
```

In the graphical editor of my_custom_list.xml, right click the list. Choose the my_custom_row from the "Custom" option in the "Preview List Content".

Comment: I'm not sure when it was added, but in Android Studio 0.8.9, I am able to add `tools:listitem="@layout/account_list_item"` to the ListView definition in XML to get the preview showing up :)

Answer (score 1):

yes of course, but you first need to create a class that extends ArrayAdapter<>

this class could be as this one:

```
public class Mylistcustom extends ArrayAdapter<String> {

private LayoutInflater mInflater;
private int mViewResourceId;
private String[] your_date;

    public Mylistcustom(Context ctx, int viewResourceId, String[] data) {

    super(ctx, viewResourceId,data);
    this.contexto=ctx;
    mInflater = (LayoutInflater)ctx.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    mViewResourceId = viewResourceId;
    this.your_data=data;



    @Override
    public int getCount() {
    return your_data.length;
}

@Override
    public String getItem(int position) {
    return your_data[position];
}

@Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
    return 0;
}

@Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    rowView = mInflater.inflate(mViewResourceId, null);// you are inflating your xml layout
    text=(textView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.textView);//find a textview in your layout, of course you can add whatever you want such as ImaveView Buttons ....
    text.setText(your_data[position]); // and set text from your_data
    return rowView;
```

}
}

and in the list view activity you only have to call the constructor and pass your data, the layout and the context

```
Myadapter = new Mylistcustom(context, R.layout.YOUR_XML_LAYOUT,DATA);

// and finally set the adapter to your list
ListView lv = (ListView) findViewById(android.R.id.list);
lv.setAdapter(Myadapter);
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, unfortunately it is not was I was looking for. I found a solution and will post it back. +1 for trying :)