# android customized list view

Tags: android, listview

I have a question in android. I am not an android expert. I want to display an employee table data in a list (list view or grid any thing). Not like a table view, the list looks like following. I think for this I need to customize the list view? Is it possible like to have a list view/grid view to customize as following? Please advice. Or any already available open source for this?

```
      [Reviewer Name (Editable)]       
               Employee Lest           
---------------------------------------
Employee1                    [Click Me]

Male (0)          Female ( )
Salary : [5999 (editable)]
Qualification
[X]BA
[ ]BSc
[ ]Matriculation
[ ]Other
[Submit Button]
---------------------------------------
Employee2                    [Click Me]

Male (0)          Female ( )
Salary : [5999 (editable)]
Qualification
[X]BA
[ ]BSc
[ ]Matriculation
[ ]Other
[Submit Button]
---------------------------------------
Employee3                    [Click Me]

Male (0)          Female ( )
Salary : [5999 (editable)]
Qualification
[X]BA
[ ]BSc
[ ]Matriculation
[ ]Other
[Submit Button]
---------------------------------------
```

Comment: I think you can use a [Custom ListView][1] 


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11203846/custom-list-row-in-listview-graphical-layout

Comment: Consider just only **one List Row**, design separate layout for that and using custom adapter inflate that list row layout to your adapter list. Simple..

Comment: Refer these links. http://www.androidhive.info/2012/02/android-custom-listview-with-image-and-text/ http://mobile.dzone.com/news/custom-listview-android http://www.framentos.com/en/android-tutorial/2012/07/16/listview-in-android-using-custom-listadapter-and-viewcache/ Hope its helpful to u :)

Comment: you can customize the listview in any way you want: http://www.thepcwizard.in/2012/09/android-creating-custom-listview-for.html , http://www.androidhive.info/2012/02/android-custom-listview-with-image-and-text/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you need to implement a custom adapter which will inflate a custom layout. Implement a 
custom adapter (by extending `BaseAdapter` class or `ArrayAdapter<Employee>` class) Check this tutorial : http://www.ezzylearning.com/tutorial.aspx?tid=1763429

Answer (score 0):

A custom listview will do the job for you.
 [Here](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/02/android-custom-listview-with-image-and-text/) is a very good tutorial for your case.
Layout of your custom listview should be something like this:

```
---------------------------------------
TextView                    Button

RadioGroup
TextView  EditText
TextView
CheckBox TextView
CheckBox TextView
CheckBox TextView
CheckBox TextView
Button
---------------------------------------
```